# Web application to manage CATIA files

Tags: c#, c++, web-applications, customization, catia

A have a question for CATIA customization experts!

I'm intend to develop a web application able to perfoms the following tasks:

1. Modify some parameters into CATIA files. eg.: change the diameter or length of a part;
2. Convert theses CATIA files to STEP files.

So, I possible do these things using CATIA API and without have CATIA software instaled on my web server?

I did some research on the WEB and I found some APIs, like "CAD.ai" that I think solve these questions. But, these APIs look so sophisticated for my purpose and I looking for develop my own code.

Any suggestion?

Comment: _But, these APIs look so sofisticated for my purpose_ - probably because CATIA is a sophisticated application. ;-)

Comment: There's a reason products like Dassault CATIA cost upwards of $60,000. This is not a trivial spec.

Answer (score 0):

Catvbs code can be incorporated in web pages and "talk' with CATIA, check Dassault Systems automation documentation which is in the installation folder of CATIA (be aware that there are differences between releases and versions of CATIA- v5, v6, 3DEx). You don't need to have CATIA but you need to check if CATIA is opened or not on client PC (and convince CATIA user to run your code from web).

By the way, from DS chm automation file you can run their codes directly in CATIA...